# What is wrong with my Regex and why?

Tags: javascript, regex

The following regex:

```
var number = /^(\+|\-|)(\d+\.|\.\d+|\d+|\d+.\d+)((e\+|e\-|e)\d+)?$/i;
```

incorrectly accepts `1+1` and `1f5` which aren't real JavasScript numbers.

I am attempting to make a regex that "matches only JavaScript-style numbers. It must support an optional minus or plus sign in front of the number, the decimal dot, and exponent notation—5e-3 or 1E10— again with an optional sign in front of the exponent. Also note that it is not necessary for there to be digits in front of or after the dot, but the number cannot be a dot alone. That is, .5 and 5. are valid JavaScript numbers, but a lone dot isn’t."

Comment: Visualize and see why: http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5E(%5C%2B%7C%5C-%7C)(%5Cd%2B%5C.%7C%5C.%5Cd%2B%7C%5Cd%2B%7C%5Cd%2B.%5Cd%2B)((e%5C%2B%7Ce%5C-%7Ce)%5Cd%2B)%3F%24%2Fi

Comment: Notice `\d+.\d+` you did not escape dot

Comment: Replace alternation with character classes; it'll help you both to simplify the regex and to speed it up (a bit). For example: `/^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?$/i`.

Comment: As a sidenote, you don't have to escape `-` outside character classes. Inside, you'll only have to do it if the symbol is not at the edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left one of your `.` unescaped. Make sure all have a backslash before it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `.`'s in your regex by `\`. Also, you need to escape all `+`  in your regex by `\`.

See [this](http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/23) demo.